# Deep link activity not opening

Tags: android

I am using below code to open an activity in my app

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>

            <data android:host="google.com"></data>
            <data android:scheme="https"></data>
            <data android:pathPattern="/.*"></data>

        </intent-filter>
```

On typing google.com on browser its not opening my activity. Also I tried with other links but no lead. I tried on clicking through mails like Gmail etc but no success.

Am I missing something.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `On typing google.com on browser` it really won't. It should only if you click google link in your browser.

Comment: I tried with other links as well but its not opening

Comment: `I tried with other links` what exactly have you tried?

Comment: yahoo.com and other links

Comment: `what exactly have you tried` to do with that links?

Comment: I want to open a link which my client want, for safety purpose I cant disclose that link. If these links will open that will also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from API 23+, you need to have a file on the website/server you are using to link to your app which contains the package name of your Android application. This `Digital Asset Links` file verifies that the app is permitted to open links from the site in question. You also need to add `android:autoVerify="true"` to the intent-filter (which flags the OS to verify your app with the domain you're trying to deep link from when it's installed). Without this, you cannot deep link from http/https into your Android app. Custom schema links (such as `myschema://data_here`) still work without needing any verification.

For more information about Android app link verification, [see here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations.html)

Also, for future reference, Apple has the same verification requirements albeit with an `apple-app-site-association` file: [see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to access through gmail. Clicking on the link opens the app activity but if I enter complete URL its not opening activity. Though I have used android:pathPattern="/.*"